# Are there any topologies generated by some $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

The Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is generated by a topology (standard one). Is the converse true? Are there any topologies generated by some $\sigma$-algebras? (Sorry that I misinterpreted the question earlier.)

Comment: Any subset of the powerset of a topological spaces generates a topology.

Comment: Do you maybe mean that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is generated by the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}^d$? Please give us some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to your question.

Comment: Every Borel $\sigma$-algebra by definition comes from (is generated by) a topology, but not every $\sigma$-algebra on a set is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a topology on that set. It's not quite clear what you're asking exactly, though.

Comment: I would think that the converse would be the following question: given a $\sigma$-algebra, is it the $\sigma$-algebra generated by some topology?

Comment: @Eric Yes. I realized now :) (Silly of me.) $\tau(\sigma(A))$ always exists for a given subset $A$ of a power set of $X$. But what kind of a topology is this? I can not imagine.

Comment: @Eric $\sigma(A)$ seems to be larger than $\tau(\sigma(A))$, correct?

Comment: @Eric The answer is "Not correct". I spoke to my teacher and he gave me examples that either $\sigma(A)$ or $\tau(\sigma(A))$ can be larger.

Answer (score 7):

Let $X$ be a set and let $\mathcal{P}(X)$ denote the power set of $X$. Every collection of subsets $S \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ generates a topology, as well as a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ as follows:

$S$ generates a topology on $X$ via
$$
 \tau(S)
:= \bigcap
  \{
    \mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)
    \mid
    \text{$\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $X$ with $S \subseteq \mathcal{T}$}
  \}.
$$
Notice that collection of topologies on the right hand side is non-empty, because it contains the discrete topology $\mathcal{P}(X)$. Because the arbitrary non-empty intersection of topologies is again a topology it follows that $\tau(S)$ is a topology on $X$. By construction it is the smallest topology on $X$ containing $S$.

Similarly $S$ generates a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, namely
$$
 \sigma(S)
:= \bigcap
  \{
    \mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)
    \mid
    \text{$\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ with $S \subseteq \mathcal{A}$}
  \}.
$$

The collection of $\sigma$-algebras on the right hand side is non-empty because it contains the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ itself, and $\sigma(S)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra because the arbitrary non-empty intersection of $\sigma$-algebras is again a $\sigma$-algebra. By construction $\sigma(S)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ containing $S$.

A Borel $\sigma$-algebra can now be defined for every topological space: If $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a topological space then the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra is defined as $\mathcal{B}((X,\mathcal{T})) = \sigma(\mathcal{T})$, i.e. it is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets of $(X,\mathcal{T})$.

[ The Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}((X,\mathcal{T}))$ then in turn also generates a topology of $X$, namely $\tau(\mathcal{B}((X,\mathcal{T})))$, which contains $\mathcal{B}((X,\mathcal{T}))$ and therefore also $\mathcal{T}$. But I think that this is not what you actually want. If for example $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is $T_1$, i.e. if the singleton sets $\{x\}$ are closed with respect to $\mathcal{T}$, then these singletons will be contained in $\mathcal{B}((X,\mathcal{T}))$, and thus open in $\tau(\mathcal{B}((X,\mathcal{T})))$. So $\tau(\mathcal{B}((X,\mathcal{T})))$ is then the discrete topology. ]

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I wonder whether there are other topologies generated by some $\sigma$-algebras. By the way, I edited my question.

Comment: Every $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ generates a topology, namely $\tau(\mathcal{A})$. More explicitely it can be shown that $\tau(\mathcal{A}) = \{\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \mid \text{$A_i \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $i \in I$}\}$, i.e. the open sets in $\tau(\mathcal{A})$ are precisely the arbitrary unions of the measurable sets of $\mathcal{A}$. But I don’t know how useful these topologies are (I guess not very much), and if they naturally occur somewhere. I am also not sure if topologies generated by a $\sigma$-algebra can be characterized differently.